# XNA/Monogame 3D - Disable Anti-Aliasing

Tags: 3d, xna, directx, monogame, xna-4.0

I'm trying to disable the anti-aliasing of my models' textures in Monogame 3D. In [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH2gB.png), the edge colors should be pure colors ((0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), etc), but they're being blended and turning all ugly. Anyone know how to turn this off? Thanks.

Comment: Antialiasing seems to be already disabled, what you actually want to disable is texture filtering. Set texture filtering mode to Nearest Neighbor.

Comment: @VTT How would I achieve this? I looked around and could not find anything about how to set the texture filtering mode. I did, however, fix the blurriness using `GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointClamp`.

Comment: You already did this. Sampler state defines filtering.

Comment: Adding that line doesn't work for me.  Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Old post but this works, similar to the answer given.

```
spriteBatch.Begin(samplerState: SamplerState.PointClamp); // prevent anti-alias when scaling up
```